# Extract explicit region (integration bounds) from ImplicitRegion

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, regions, internals

Using an `ImplicitRegion` in `NIntegrate` by far best performance is obtained by using `Method->"UnitCubeRescaling"` in my case. In order to get further insight into the integration (and possibly either increase performance further or easily port it to c++), i would like to extract the transformation used by Mathematica in order to rescale the integrand to a hypercube.

Explicit example:

`ImplicitRegion` defined as:

```
localA=200; localB=1; localC=900;
reg = ImplicitRegion[{
         0 <= y <= x && -1 <= z <= 1 && 
         -x^2 + y^2 + localA^2 + 2*localA*y*z > 0 && 
         localB <= x <= localC}, {x, y, z}];

NIntegrate[f[x, y, z], {x, y, z} ∈ reg,
 Method -> {"UnitCubeRescaling", "FunctionalRangesOnly" -> True, 
   Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityHandler" -> None}}]
```

The Implicit region arises from Heaviside theta functions with a nonlinear arguments. I'm looking for a conceptual solution, as I also have more complicated examples, but I would be grateful for any solutions to this particular examples as well.

Comment: You may find useful information [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#46192878).

Comment: Trying the given transformation there was actually my starting point in trying to resolve this analytically, unfortunately I cannot even map the implicit region to a nested integral (after which i would be done using the given transformation from your link).

Comment: You might be interested in `CylindricalDecomposition[]`.

Comment: This looks promising, thanks. It could be possible to "guess" the general case by looking several numerical configurations.